# By taking limits both sides of:$ x_{n+1}^2=2x_n+3$, calculate the limit of $x_n$ as $n$ approaches infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits

[image]

I have no idea how to take the limit on both sides of the equation...

Comment: Hint: if $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=X$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n+1}=X$...

Comment: Let L^2 = 2L + 3 <=> L^2-2L-3 = 0 <=> (L-3)(L+1) = 0 <=> L = -1 or L = 3. Since xn is strictly increasing, and 3>-1, it follows that as n approaches positive infinity, the limit L = 3. Is this correct?

Comment: $x_n$ isn't necessarily strictly increasing - consider $x_1=12$< for instance. But while you need a bit more to be rigorous, you've got the right idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**: You solve the equation: $\ell^2=2\ell+3$